# How to prevent escaping of specific(certain) HTML tags in java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

To prevent Html injections, I am trying to escape HTML tags on my java code and save them on the database.

When I need to fetch the same from the database and send it to the front end, I do not want all the HTML tags to get unescaped. Is there any way to unescape only certain text formatting tags(bold, italic, underline...) leaving the rest escaped?

Example:

Suppose I have a strong tag inside it an anchor tag than when unescaping back from the database I should unescape only strong tag not HTML

Can anyone suggest to me the way or solution to do this?

Comment: 1- If possible don't store html in database. rather store raw information  in data base and  do all formatting stuff  in html. 




2- If not possible to store raw data in database : I don't really understand what you are trying to do. But if you want to manipulate html code in java i suppose third party library like https://jsoup.org/ can help.

Comment: read this https://howtodoinjava.com/java/string/escape-html-encode-string/